# jenkins kubernetes pipeline dsl does not read containers definition

Tags: maven, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

We have configured two Kubernetes clouds in our jenkins

- kubernetes: this one runs all the build jobs related to setting up infra, building spring boot apps and their docker images etc; it's our devops automation apps cluster
- apps-dev: this is where all our apps are deployed so it's our runtime cluster, non production

I'm trying to run cucumber tests via maven but as we do not expose services via alb in the apps-dev cluster I wanted to run the maven job as a pod on the `apps-dev` cluster.

We've added pod label to the template but jenkins pipeline starts with just jnlp container.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud 'apps-dev'
            yamlFile '''
                apiVersion: v1
                kind: Pod
                metadata:
                  labels:
                    jenkins/label: jenkins-apps-dev-agent
                    namespace: jenkins-jobs
                  containers:     
                    - name: mavenjdk11
                      image: maven:3.8.2-adoptopenjdk-11
                      resources:
                        limits:
                          memory: "512Mi"
                          cpu: "500m"
                        requests:
                          memory: "256Mi"
                          cpu: "100m"
                      command:
                        - sleep
                      args:
                        - 99d 
                  volumes:
                    - name: sharedvolume
                      emptyDir: {}                             
            '''
        }
    }
    ...
```

and the logs

```
Created Pod: foo jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][LoggingEnabled] Successfully enabled logging for pod
Still waiting to schedule task
‘foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq’ is offline
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][Scheduled] Successfully assigned jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq to fargate-ip-176-24-3-48.ec2.internal
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][Pulling] Pulling image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4"
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][TaintManagerEviction] Cancelling deletion of Pod jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" in 15.29095263s
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][jenkins-jobs/foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq][Started] Started container jnlp
Agent foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq is provisioned from template foo_foo-integration_foo-feature-tests_17-mnscq-lz8wj
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    buildUrl: "https://jenkins.cloud.bar.com/job/foo/job/foo-integration/job/foo-feature-tests/17/"
    runUrl: "job/foo/job/foo-integration/job/foo-feature-tests/17/"
  labels:
    jenkins/label-digest: "baf69ff51703705e7e8252b6f5a54fc663dae21d"
    jenkins/label: "foo_foo-integration_foo-feature-tests_17-mnscq"
  name: "foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq"
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq"
    - name: "JENKINS_WEB_SOCKET"
      value: "true"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "foo-foo-integration-foo-feature-tests-17-m-4hhpq"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "https://jenkins.cloud.bar.com/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in my yaml, it should have been

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins/label: jenkins-apps-dev-agent
    namespace: jenkins-jobs
spec:
  containers:     
    - name: mavenjdk11
      image: maven:3.8.2-adoptopenjdk-11
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "512Mi"
          cpu: "500m"
        requests:
          memory: "256Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
      command:
        - sleep
      args:
        - 99d 
  volumes:
    - name: sharedvolume
      emptyDir: {}
```

the `spec:` before containers was missing